# ng-include doesnt work after interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I have a div with the following,

```
<div id="contenido" ng-include="'partials/busqueda.html'"> </div>
```

After adding an interceptor to my page it stop working,

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, Auth) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                if (Auth.authz.token) {
                    Auth.authz.updateToken(5).success(function() {
                        config.headers = config.headers || {};
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Auth.authz.token;

                        deferred.resolve(config);
                    }).error(function() {
                        deferred.reject('Failed to refresh token');
                    });
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    });

    app.config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    });
```

If I comment the lines $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');, ng-include works again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `ng-include` to uses `$http` service to download templates. The interceptor hence affects request made by `ng-include` too.

In your scenario the interceptor maybe failing to authorize, and doing a reject. This is causing template loading to fail.

You can check at the start of the request interceptor for type of request (using `config` object) and skip the token check for static html.